# mongodb query $in operator, fetch by ObjectId in Array

Tags: mongodb

All my documents have a structure like this:

```
{
   operational: {availableFleet: [Objectid('5bad3f452641a1186d21b5f8'), ...]}
}
```

So every document has an operational key with many other keys inside, one of them being availableFleet which is an Array of multiple ObjectIds

I want to retrieve all documents that contain one specific ObjectId inside the availableFleet Array.

Here's my query:

```
{operational: {availableFleet: {$in: [ObjectId('5bad3f452641a1186d21b5f8')]}}}
```

However, it's returning nothing.

I'm using the MongoDB Compass GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
{'operational.availableFleet': ObjectId('5bad3f452641a1186d21b5f8')}
```

No need for `$in` as this is for the case of multiple options for the `ObjectId('5bad3f452641a1186d21b5f8')`.

And nested objects are marked with a `.`